# Iam getting error after inserting data in to sqlite3

Tags: iphone, xcode

I use following code to insert into sqllite using iphone
-(void)save{

```
AlarmData *alarm=[CallSettings getAlarm];
alarm.subject=subjectText.text;
alarm.sound=tempDefault;
NSDate *dat=[datePicker date];
NSString *da=(NSString *)[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",dat];
alarm.date=da;

//alarmData.date=da;
NSLog([CallSettings getAlarm].subject);
NSLog([CallSettings getAlarm].no1);
NSLog([CallSettings getAlarm].lname);
NSLog([CallSettings getAlarm].name);
NSLog([CallSettings getAlarm].date);
NSLog([CallSettings getAlarm].sound);


NSString *fullName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",alarm.name,alarm.lname];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appointment.sql"];
sqlite3 *database;
if(sqlite3_open([filePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    const char *sqlStatement = "select * from Alarm";

    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Loop through the results and add them to the feeds array

        compiledStatement=NULL;

        const char *sql = "insert into Alarm(name) values ('Ahmed')";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK);
        else {
            if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            else
                //SQLite provides a method to get the last primary key inserted by using sqlite3_last_insert_rowid
                //coffeeID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);
                NSLog(@"Value is inserted");
            //  sqlite3_reset(compiledStatement);
        }
    }




    }




}
 sqlite3_close(database);
```

}// end of the save method

When call this method app crashes and following error occurs

2011-01-10 19:23:56.307 Appointment[521:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
2011-01-10 19:23:56.321 Appointment[521:207] Stack: (
    843263261,
    825818644,
    842812211,
    842812115,
    863177559,
    21701,
    844154820,
    19557,
    846200172,
    843020431,
    844097412,
    844097260,
    844097204,
    844096268,
    844356084,
    846188672,
    862896011,
    843011267,
    843009055,
    860901832,
    843738160,
    843731504,
    10565,
    10480
)
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'NSException'
Program received signal:  “SIGABRT”.
(gdb)

and apps dont run next time untill and unless i delete the app from my device I think database file crashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement) instead of compiledStatement = NULL;
Just read the documentation and you'll understand why. Or you could use another variable for sqlite3_stmt, for INSERT.